# Infinite Webpack watch loop - how to ignore changes to .js files, etc

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

My `webpack -w` command using ts-loader is in an infinite loop. I am guessing it's because webpack -w is seeing changes to .js files, so that causes the *loop*:

> webpack -w => ts transpile => .js changes => webpack -w

has anyone seen this before? Is the best thing to do to tell webpack -w to ignore .js files? How can I do that?

Here is my webpack.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {

  entry: ['babel-polyfill', './lib/index.ts'],

  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname + '/dist'),
    filename: 'suman.js'
  },

  module: {

    rules: [
      // all files with a `.ts` or `.tsx` extension will be handled by `ts-loader`
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /^\.d.ts$/,
        loader: 'ignore-loader'
      }
    ],

  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      fs: require.resolve('suman-browser-polyfills/modules/fs'),
      process: require.resolve('suman-browser-polyfills/modules/process'),
    },
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
  }

};
```

**Unfortunately**, webpack does not seem to support an --ignore option at the command line:

```
$ webpack -w --ignore=*.js
webpack 2.7.0
Usage: https://webpack.js.org/api/cli/
Usage without config file: webpack <entry> [<entry>] <output>
Usage with config file: webpack

Config options:
  --config  Path to the config file
                         [string] [default: webpack.config.js or webpackfile.js]
  --env     Environment passed to the config, when it is a function

Basic options:
  --context    The root directory for resolving entry point and stats
                                       [string] [default: The current directory]
  --entry      The entry point                                          [string]
  --watch, -w  Watch the filesystem for changes                        [boolean]
  --debug      Switch loaders to debug mode                            [boolean]
  --devtool    Enable devtool for better debugging experience (Example:
               --devtool eval-cheap-module-source-map)                  [string]
  -d           shortcut for --debug --devtool eval-cheap-module-source-map
               --output-pathinfo                                       [boolean]
  -p           shortcut for --optimize-minimize --define
               process.env.NODE_ENV="production"                       [boolean]
  --progress   Print compilation progress in percentage                [boolean]

Module options:
  --module-bind       Bind an extension to a loader                     [string]
  --module-bind-post                                                    [string]
  --module-bind-pre                                                     [string]

Output options:
  --output-path                 The output path for compilation assets
                                       [string] [default: The current directory]
  --output-filename             The output filename of the bundle
                                                   [string] [default: [name].js]
  --output-chunk-filename       The output filename for additional chunks
       [string] [default: filename with [id] instead of [name] or [id] prefixed]
  --output-source-map-filename  The output filename for the SourceMap   [string]
  --output-public-path          The public path for the assets          [string]
  --output-jsonp-function       The name of the jsonp function used for chunk
                                loading                                 [string]
  --output-pathinfo             Include a comment with the request for every
                                dependency (require, import, etc.)     [boolean]
  --output-library              Expose the exports of the entry point as library
                                                                        [string]
  --output-library-target       The type for exposing the exports of the entry
                                point as library                        [string]

Advanced options:
  --records-input-path       Path to the records file (reading)         [string]
  --records-output-path      Path to the records file (writing)         [string]
  --records-path             Path to the records file                   [string]
  --define                   Define any free var in the bundle          [string]
  --target                   The targeted execution environment         [string]
  --cache                    Enable in memory caching
                      [boolean] [default: It's enabled by default when watching]
  --watch-stdin, --stdin     Exit the process when stdin is closed     [boolean]
  --watch-aggregate-timeout  Timeout for gathering changes while watching
  --watch-poll               The polling interval for watching (also enable
                             polling)                                  [boolean]
  --hot                      Enables Hot Module Replacement            [boolean]
  --prefetch                 Prefetch this request (Example: --prefetch
                             ./file.js)                                 [string]
  --provide                  Provide these modules as free vars in all modules
                             (Example: --provide jQuery=jquery)         [string]
  --labeled-modules          Enables labeled modules                   [boolean]
  --plugin                   Load this plugin                           [string]
  --bail                     Abort the compilation on first error      [boolean]
  --profile                  Profile the compilation and include information in
                             stats                                     [boolean]

Resolving options:
  --resolve-alias         Setup a module alias for resolving (Example:
                          jquery-plugin=jquery.plugin)                  [string]
  --resolve-extensions    Setup extensions that should be used to resolve
                          modules (Example: --resolve-extensions .es6 .js)
                                                                         [array]
  --resolve-loader-alias  Setup a loader alias for resolving            [string]

Optimizing options:
  --optimize-max-chunks      Try to keep the chunk count below a limit
  --optimize-min-chunk-size  Try to keep the chunk size above a limit
  --optimize-minimize        Minimize javascript and switches loaders to
                             minimizing                                [boolean]

Stats options:
  --color, --colors           Enables/Disables colors on the console
                                           [boolean] [default: (supports-color)]
  --sort-modules-by           Sorts the modules list by property in module
                                                                        [string]
  --sort-chunks-by            Sorts the chunks list by property in chunk[string]
  --sort-assets-by            Sorts the assets list by property in asset[string]
  --hide-modules              Hides info about modules                 [boolean]
  --display-exclude           Exclude modules in the output             [string]
  --display-modules           Display even excluded modules in the output
                                                                       [boolean]
  --display-max-modules       Sets the maximum number of visible modules in
                              output                                    [number]
  --display-chunks            Display chunks in the output             [boolean]
  --display-entrypoints       Display entry points in the output       [boolean]
  --display-origins           Display origins of chunks in the output  [boolean]
  --display-cached            Display also cached modules in the output[boolean]
  --display-cached-assets     Display also cached assets in the output [boolean]
  --display-reasons           Display reasons about module inclusion in the
                              output                                   [boolean]
  --display-depth             Display distance from entry point for each module
                                                                       [boolean]
  --display-used-exports      Display information about used exports in modules
                              (Tree Shaking)                           [boolean]
  --display-provided-exports  Display information about exports provided from
                              modules                                  [boolean]
  --display-error-details     Display details about errors             [boolean]
  --verbose                   Show more details                        [boolean]

Options:
  --help, -h     Show help                                             [boolean]
  --version, -v  Show version number                                   [boolean]
  --json, -j     Prints the result as JSON.                            [boolean]

Unknown argument: ignore
```

Comment: It seems that Webpack does not have an ignore option - https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/5874

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `webpack.config.js`:

```
// at the top:
const WatchIgnorePlugin = require('watch-ignore-webpack-plugin');

 ...

plugins: new WatchIgnorePlugin([/your-ignored-file\.js/]),
```

Reference: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/watch-ignore-plugin/

It also requires `npm install --save --dev watch-ignore-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: Things may have changed since this answer, but for me it was `import { WatchIgnorePlugin } from "webpack";` and `plugins: [ new WatchIgnorePlugin({ paths: [/\.*\.js/] }) ]` Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I went down the path of trying to get `watch-ignore-webpack-plugin` to work with webpack 5.7.x but couldn't get it to work. Then I discovered that webpack watch options support ignoring folders [here](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/#watchoptionsignored)

Which looks something like this in your webpack config

```js
module.exports = {
  //...
  watchOptions: {
    ignored: '**/node_modules',
  },
};
```