# React Application Reloading (Webpack) when Saving Image to Server

Tags: react-native, webpack, react-redux, webpack-dev-server

I am writing a **React App** in Visual Studio 2019 (ASP NET Core 3.1) and having an issue where the App reloads in the browser when I save a new profile picture (to disc).

This is causing issue on the page as its running the UseEffect() before it begins processing the async response with the updated info.

I am able to reproduce this behavior by simply overwriting or deleting the image file from file explorer. And it is important to NOTE that if I attempt to move my images folder outside of SRC folder, I get an error saying this is not allowed.

My initial investigation tells me this has to do with **Webpack** watching the images folder. But every attempt I have made to prevent it from watching the folder has failed. I have gone over the Webpack documentation many times but nothing seems to change.

I have two config files in my application **Webpack.config.js** and **WebpackDevServer.config.js**. It doesn't seem to matter what config I modify it always reloads the App. I have also tried setting the ENV mode to 'development' but again no dice.

Can someone please tell me how to modify the webpack configs to avoid the application from reloading.

If you can provide the above back with the necessary change it would be MUCH appreciated.

src\Images\Users\Profile Pictures - is the path I would like to ignore.

**Webpack.config.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
// @remove-on-eject-end
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const safePostCssParser = require('postcss-safe-parser');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const paths = require('./paths');
const modules = require('./modules');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');
// @remove-on-eject-begin
const getCacheIdentifier = require('react-dev-utils/getCacheIdentifier');
// @remove-on-eject-end
const postcssNormalize = require('postcss-normalize');

const appPackageJson = require(paths.appPackageJson);

// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
// Some apps do not need the benefits of saving a web request, so not inlining the chunk
// makes for a smoother build process.
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

const isExtendingEslintConfig = process.env.EXTEND_ESLINT === 'true';

const imageInlineSizeLimit = parseInt(
  process.env.IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT || '10000'
);

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function (webpackEnv) {

  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  // Variable used for enabling profiling in Production
  // passed into alias object. Uses a flag if passed into the build command
  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes('--profile');

  // We will provide `paths.publicUrlOrPath` to our app
  // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
  // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
    const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        // css is located in `static/css`, use '../../' to locate index.html folder
        // in production `paths.publicUrlOrPath` can be a relative path
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {},
      },
      {
.....
```

**WebpackDevServer.config.js**

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
// @remove-on-eject-end
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const errorOverlayMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/errorOverlayMiddleware');
const evalSourceMapMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/evalSourceMapMiddleware');
const noopServiceWorkerMiddleware = require('react-dev-utils/noopServiceWorkerMiddleware');
const ignoredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/ignoredFiles');
const redirectServedPath = require('react-dev-utils/redirectServedPathMiddleware');
const paths = require('./paths');
const getHttpsConfig = require('./getHttpsConfig');

const host = process.env.HOST || '0.0.0.0';
const sockHost = process.env.WDS_SOCKET_HOST;
const sockPath = process.env.WDS_SOCKET_PATH; // default: '/sockjs-node'
const sockPort = process.env.WDS_SOCKET_PORT;

module.exports = function(proxy, allowedHost) {
  return {
    // WebpackDevServer 2.4.3 introduced a security fix that prevents remote
    // websites from potentially accessing local content through DNS rebinding:
    // https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/887
    // https://medium.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server-middleware-security-issues-1489d950874a
    // However, it made several existing use cases such as development in cloud
    // environment or subdomains in development significantly more complicated:
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2271
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2233
    // While we're investigating better solutions, for now we will take a
    // compromise. Since our WDS configuration only serves files in the `public`
    // folder we won't consider accessing them a vulnerability. However, if you
    // use the `proxy` feature, it gets more dangerous because it can expose
    // remote code execution vulnerabilities in backends like Django and Rails.
    // So we will disable the host check normally, but enable it if you have
    // specified the `proxy` setting. Finally, we let you override it if you
    // really know what you're doing with a special environment variable.
    disableHostCheck:
      !proxy || process.env.DANGEROUSLY_DISABLE_HOST_CHECK === 'true',
    // Enable gzip compression of generated files.
    compress: true,
    // Silence WebpackDevServer's own logs since they're generally not useful.
    // It will still show compile warnings and errors with this setting.
    clientLogLevel: 'none',
    // By default WebpackDevServer serves physical files from current directory
    // in addition to all the virtual build products that it serves from memory.
    // This is confusing because those files won’t automatically be available in
    // production build folder unless we copy them. However, copying the whole
    // project directory is dangerous because we may expose sensitive files.
    // Instead, we establish a convention that only files in `public` directory
    // get served. Our build script will copy `public` into the `build` folder.
    // In `index.html`, you can get URL of `public` folder with %PUBLIC_URL%:
    // <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    // In JavaScript code, you can access it with `process.env.PUBLIC_URL`.
    // Note that we only recommend to use `public` folder as an escape hatch
    // for files like `favicon.ico`, `manifest.json`, and libraries that are
    // for some reason broken when imported through webpack. If you just want to
    // use an image, put it in `src` and `import` it from JavaScript instead.
    contentBase: paths.appPublic,
    contentBasePublicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath,
    // By default files from `contentBase` will not trigger a page reload.
    watchContentBase: true,
    // Enable hot reloading server. It will provide WDS_SOCKET_PATH endpoint
    // for the WebpackDevServer client so it can learn when the files were
    // updated. The WebpackDevServer client is included as an entry point
    // in the webpack development configuration. Note that only changes
    // to CSS are currently hot reloaded. JS changes will refresh the browser.
    hot: true,
    // Use 'ws' instead of 'sockjs-node' on server since we're using native
    // websockets in `webpackHotDevClient`.
    transportMode: 'ws',
    // Prevent a WS client from getting injected as we're already including
    // `webpackHotDevClient`.
    injectClient: false,
    // Enable custom sockjs pathname for websocket connection to hot reloading server.
    // Enable custom sockjs hostname, pathname and port for websocket connection
    // to hot reloading server.
    sockHost,
    sockPath,
    sockPort,
    // It is important to tell WebpackDevServer to use the same "publicPath" path as
    // we specified in the webpack config. When homepage is '.', default to serving
    // from the root.
    // remove last slash so user can land on `/test` instead of `/test/`
    publicPath: paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1),
    // WebpackDevServer is noisy by default so we emit custom message instead
    // by listening to the compiler events with `compiler.hooks[...].tap` calls above.
    quiet: true,
    // Reportedly, this avoids CPU overload on some systems.
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/293
    // src/node_modules is not ignored to support absolute imports
    // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1065

    
      watchOptions: {
          ignored: ignoredFiles(paths.appSrc)
    },
...
```

Thanks Again,

Adam

Comment: I have tried to implement this documentation in countless ways (https://webpack.js.org/configuration/watch/). If anyone could please show me how to correctly implement this it would be much appreciated as I'm new to React.

Comment: I have also tried ignoring the folder via Plugin (  new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin(['src/Images']), ).

Comment: Also tried these steps: (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46899159/infinite-webpack-watch-loop-how-to-ignore-changes-to-js-files-etc)
1. npm install --save --dev watch-ignore-webpack-plugin
2. // at the top of Webpack.config.js:
const WatchIgnorePlugin = require('watch-ignore-webpack-plugin');
3. // In the plugins section of Webpack.config.js
plugins: 
new WatchIgnorePlugin([/your-ignored-file\.js/]),
as
new webpack.WatchIgnorePlugin([/Images\.bmp$/, /Images\.gif$/, /Images\.jpe?g$/, /Images\.png$/]),