# Exlcude Folder From Watch

Tags: webpack

Hello all I'm still trying to figure out how to exclude my Dynamic Images folder in Webpack. I have tried both Watch option Exclude and Watch Ignore Plugin. If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be appreciated I have spent several days attempting to figure this out with no success.

Please find issue details here: [React Application Reloading (Webpack) when Saving Image to Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65986839/react-application-reloading-webpack-when-saving-image-to-server)

also

I have no clue if this section is some how overriding my Exclude/IgnoreWatch entries.

```
   // "oneOf" will traverse all following loaders until one will
          // match the requirements. When no loader matches it will fall
          // back to the "file" loader at the end of the loader list.
          oneOf: [
            // "url" loader works like "file" loader except that it embeds assets
            // smaller than specified limit in bytes as data URLs to avoid requests.
            // A missing `test` is equivalent to a match.
            {
              test: [/\.bmp$/, /\.gif$/, /\.jpe?g$/, /\.png$/],
                  loader: require.resolve('url-loader'),
         
              options: {
                limit: imageInlineSizeLimit,
                name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              },
            },
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the main issue here was that I was using **REQUIRE** around my images. Even if this image location is in the public folder or excluded from webpack it would seem that its still tracked by the **REQUIRE** tag. To fix this I moved my images to the public folder and used URL paths to reference images.

This fixed the App Reloading issue.